# Can not get videos to play on ipad or iPhone?

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, video, fancybox

I have looked everywhere to an answer to this, and it is all very confusing.

I can not get my videos to play on either an ipad or iphone.

They play on other devices including androids/desktops. I have converted them many times using Miro video converter and handbrake, I have tried reducing the file size. I have tried removing the poster tags. I have come to the conclusion there must be something wrong with my html, which look like this:

```
<div id="blackbox_2" style="display: none">
<video title="BlackBox Sessions Part 2"  class="video" preload="auto" controls>
<source src="videos/BlackBoxPt.2 copy.mp4"  type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
<source src="videos/BlackBoxPt.2.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
<source src="videos/BlackBoxPt.2.ogv"  type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
<object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
data="flowplayer-5"> 
<param name="movie" value="flowplayer-5" /> 
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /> 
<param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip": {"url": "http://kimcolemanprojects.com/videos/BlackBoxPt.2.appleuniversal.mp4", "autoPlay":false, "autoBuffering":true}}' /> 
</object>
</video>  </div>
```

This html I got from dive into html. On the iPad/iphone you can see the video play button in the middle, however when you click on it nothing happens.

The page with the videos is here http://kimcolemanprojects.com/video-lighting.html

I have several videos on this page that are display in a fancy box.

If anybody can help guide me in the right direction I would be very grateful, this problem I'am finding very irritating.

Thanks
Angela

Comment: The code works on iOS stand-alone, as demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuCLm/). Have you got any event handlers on the video that might prevent the video from playing (`e.preventDefault()`, `return false` etc)?

Comment: yes, I have a dragdivscroll jquery event that might be interfering. Any idea how I get around it with out loosing this piece of script. The script is found on this page http://kimcolemanprojects.com/video-lighting.html (same page as above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided the easiest option to this problem was to stream all my videos through youtube and vimeo. That way they work on everything.