# flowplayer ipad stop looping

Tags: javascript, html, ios, flowplayer

I'm having trouble with Flowplayer.  I get the videos to run and everything on the iOS devices, however once the video ends it immediately starts playing again. or it'll drop the video, but the audio loops again.  It's almost as if `continuousPlay` is set to true.

here's the code I'm working with.  Let me know if I've done something odd, or am just forgetting to add something that will get the video to stop when it should.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

the HTML code:

`<div style="display: block; width: 640px; height: 360px; margin: 0 auto;" id="player1">
                </div>`

The script code:

```
flowplayer("player1", { src: "/flowplayer/flowplayer.swf", wmode: "direct" }, {
        plugins: { controls: null }
  , clip: { url: 'Videos/vid.mp4'
    , autoPlay: true
    , autoBuffering: true
    , bufferLength: 7
    , accelerated: true
    , continuousPlay: false
    , loop: false
    , onBeforePause: function () { return false; }
    , onBeforeSeek: function () { return false; }
    , onBeforeStop: function () { return false; }
    , onBeforeFinish: function () { ShowNextButton(); }
  }
  , onLoad: function () { this.setVolume(80); }
  , onFinish: function () { ShowNextButton(); }
  , onKeyPress: function () { return false; }
    }).ipad();
function ShowNextButton() {
        $f().onBeforeClick(function () { return false; });
        $f().hide();
        var nextButton = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_btnNext');
        nextButton.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        nextButton.style.display = 'inline';
        nextButton.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this works just fine for laptops and desktops.  so far as I can tell it's only a problem for the iOS devices.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but looks like you are using flash flowplayer, and how will it work under iOS which doesn't support flash?

Comment: @YudongLi Flowplayer handles that somehow, that's the reason for the `}).ipad();`.  I've seen the videos pop up with quicktime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can not get videos to play on ipad or iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415269/can-not-get-videos-to-play-on-ipad-or-iphone)